# Python df.groupby(level=0).mean() looses columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

So I wrote a program that generates analytical data, it has 60 rows and 37 columns. It concats perfectly, so I have all the tables I need going in order one after one (downwards). No columns or rows are missing.

[example of rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk5pB.png)

But when I run

df_grouped = df_concat.groupby(level=0).mean()

it returns a table with only 14 columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take mean of only numerical columns I guess this is why you might be loosing columns.

Comment: is there an easy way to make all of my columns numerical? they are all numbers

Comment: you could go through each column, assign them `astype(float)` and then try it. Hope this helps!